# Bash redirect stderr to file after for loop

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following script that checks for installed/uninstalled packages:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEPENDENCIES="build-essential pkg-config qt4-qmake libqt4-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev"
for dep in $DEPENDENCIES; do
    dpkg -l $dep | grep "$dep"
done | sort
```

the result is:

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libavformat-dev
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libavcodec-dev
ii  build-essential 12.1ubuntu2  amd64        Informational list of build-essential packages
ii  pkg-config     0.29.1-0ubuntu1 amd64        manage compile and link flags for libraries
un  libqt4-dev                   (no description available)
un  qt4-qmake                    (no description available)
```

which is what I expect. I would then like to redirect stdout and stderr to a file `depend.out`. So I modify the last line of the script to: `done | sort &> depend.out`. But the contents of `depend.out` are:

```
ii  build-essential 12.1ubuntu2  amd64        Informational list of build-essential packages
ii  pkg-config     0.29.1-0ubuntu1 amd64        manage compile and link flags for libraries
un  libqt4-dev     <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  qt4-qmake      <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Why are the lines in bold (uninstalled packages) missing even if I use the redirection operator `&>`?

Comment: If the first command (for....done) has an error, then error is printed on /dev/stderr and is not fed to the following pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, use:

```
command 2>&1
```

**Demonstration:**

```
ls unexisting-path 2>&1 | cat > /dev/null
```

Here, `ls` will produce an error output. This output is redirected to `stdout`, so it gets caught by the pipe `|` and sent to `cat`, which outputs it to `stdout` too. To prove it, `> /dev/null` is added, and as expected, nothing is displayed.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I replaced the last line with: `done 2>&1 | sort > depend.out`

Answer (score 1):

most probably these lines were written to your stderr therefore they weren't redirected to the pipe (instead written on the tty)
if you want stderr to be processed by the pipe as well you need to redirect it to stderr manually before piping (as pipe only acts on stdout)

try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEPENDENCIES="build-essential pkg-config qt4-qmake libqt4-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev"
for dep in $DEPENDENCIES; do
    dpkg -l $dep 2>&1 | grep "$dep"
done | sort
```